# scala mixing view and strict collection in for expression

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This piece of scala code mixes view with strict List in a for expression:

```
val list = List.range(1, 4)
def compute(n: Int) = {
  println("Computing "+n)
  n * 2
}

val view = for (n <- list.view; k<-List(1,2)) yield compute(n)
val x = view(0)
```

The output is:

```
Computing 1
Computing 1
Computing 2
Computing 2
Computing 3
Computing 3
Computing 1
Computing 1
```

I expected that it should just have the last 2 lines "Computing 1" in the output. Why would it computed all the values eagerly? And why it then recomputed the values again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably, access by index forces the view to be computed. Also, notice that you flatmap the `list` with something which is not lazy (`k` is not a view).

Compare the following:

```
// 0) Your example
val v0 = List.range(1, 4).view.flatMap(n => List(1,2).map(k => compute(n)))
v0(0) // Computing 1 
      // Computing 1
      // Computing 2
      // Computing 2
      // Computing 3
      // Computing 3
      // Computing 1
      // Computing 1

v0(0) // Computing 1
      // Computing 1

// 1) Your example, but access by head and not by index
val v1 = List.range(1, 4).view.flatMap(n => List(1,2).map(k => compute(n)))
v1.head // Computing 1 
        // Computing 1

// 2) Do not mix views and strict lists
val v2 = List.range(1, 4).view.flatMap(n => List(1,2).view.map(k => compute(n)))
v2(0) // Computing 1
```

Regarding example 0, notice that views are not like streams; while streams do cache their results, lazy views do not (they just compute lazily, i.e., by-need, on access). It seems that indexed-access requires computing the entire list, and then another computation is needed to actually access the element by index.

You may ask why indexed access in example 2 does not compute the entire list. This requires an understanding of how things work underneath; in particular, we may see the difference of the method calls from example 0 wrt example 2 in the following excerpts:

**Example 0**

```
java.lang.Exception scala.collection.SeqViewLike$FlatMapped.$anonfun$index$1(SeqViewLike.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$FlatMapped.index(SeqViewLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$FlatMapped.index$(SeqViewLike.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$5.index$lzycompute(SeqViewLike.scala:197)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$5.index(SeqViewLike.scala:197)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$FlatMapped.length(SeqViewLike.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$FlatMapped.length$(SeqViewLike.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$5.length(SeqViewLike.scala:197)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$FlatMapped.apply(SeqViewLike.scala:86)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$FlatMapped.apply$(SeqViewLike.scala:85)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$5.apply(SeqViewLike.scala:197)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
Computing 1
```

**Example 2**

```
java.lang.Exception scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcII$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcII$sp.java:12)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$Mapped.apply(SeqViewLike.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$Mapped.apply$(SeqViewLike.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$4.apply(SeqViewLike.scala:196)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$FlatMapped.apply(SeqViewLike.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$FlatMapped.apply$(SeqViewLike.scala:85)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$5.apply(SeqViewLike.scala:197)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
Computing 1
```

In particular, you see that example 0 results in a call of `Flatmapped.length` (which needs to evaluate the entire list).

Comment: If flatmap a List view with a List caused the result to be fully computed upon first accessing of an element, then why v0(0) in the example prints the  last 2 lines of "Computing 1"?

Comment: Good answer. It seems that in example 0, the length of flatmap is cached, not the values, so if we do a v0(1) after v0(0), it wont recompute the list to get the length.

Answer (score 0):

view here is a [`SeqView[Int,Seq[_]]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/SeqView.html), which is immutable and recomputes every item when iterated over.

You could access just the first by explicitly using the `.iterator`:

```
@ view.iterator.next
Computing 1
Computing 1
res11: Int = 2
```

Or explicitly make it a List (eg. if you need to reuse many entries):

```
@ val view2: List[Int] = view.toList
Computing 1
Computing 1
Computing 2
Computing 2
Computing 3
Computing 3
view2: List[Int] = List(2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6)

@ view2(0)
res13: Int = 2
```